# CAST from number to varchar is returning exponential value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying a number column to varchar in SQL select statement. It is returning in exponential value. How can I get as it is in string

```
 Select CAST([Loan Number] as nVARCHAR(50)) as strLoanNumber
 From 
 [tbl_DS] Where  [Loan]  like '%CWALT_2006%'
```

`Actual value` is `127160640`

`Returning value` is  `1.27161e+008`

Comment: I had a similar issue: I had a text field containing numeric values that got imported as float in SQL Server

My workaround was casting the float to an int, and then casting the int as an nvarchar. In my case, the query was
`select cast(CAST(float_field as int) as nvarchar(25))`

Not very pretty, but quite simple and did the trick for me. It's only valid for integer values stored as a float. If the origin data actually is a float, you might want to check the answers from the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 convert(nvarchar(50),[loan number])
```